# CodeIgniter don't get echo data from controller to Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

The ajax request is working and access the success function, the problem is when I try to use the data provide by the `echo json_encode($data)`.

`$data['status']` and `$data['error_list']`

I having the follow error : **Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined**

Can you guys tell me why it's happening  ?

**Controller:**

```
    public function get_user()
    {
        $result = false; 
        $data["error_list"] = array();
        $data["status"] = false;

        $email = $this->input->post("email");
        $password = $this->input->post("password");


        if (empty($email)) {
            $data["error_list"] = "O email deve ser preenchido";
        } else {
            $this->load->model("M_login");
            $result = $this->M_login->get_user($email);
        }


        if($result)
        {
            if(password_verify($password, $result->password)) 
            {
                $this->session->set_userdata("user_id", $result->id);
                $this->session->set_userdata("user_name", $result->nome);
                $data["status"] = true;
            } else {
                $data["error_list"]= "Credenciais invalidas";    
            }    
        }
        else
        {
            $data["error_list"] = "Credenciais invalias";  
        }
        echo json_encode($data); 

    }
```

**Ajax request:**

```
    $(function(){

          // quando ocorrer o submite no form esse evento sera carregado
          $("#login-formulario").submit(function(){

              //chamando a funcao ajax 
              $.ajax({
                  type: "post", //tipo da requisicao
                  url: BASE_URL + "login/get_user", //url que será chamada
                  dataType: "JSON",
                  data: $(this).serialize(),
                  beforeSend: function(){
                      clearError();
                      $("#loading").html(loadingImg());
                  },
                  success: function(){
                      if(data['status'] == true){
                          clearError();
                          $("#loading").html(loadingtrue());
                       }
                      else{

                          ShowError(data['error_list']); 
                      }
                  },
                  error: function(response){
                     console.log(response);
                  } 
              })
              return false;
          })
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**i Hope this help you**

```
                 success: function(data){
                      if(data.status == true){
                          clearError();
                          $("#loading").html(loadingtrue());
                       }
                      else{

                          ShowError(data.error_list); 
                      }
                  },
```

Comment: Worked ! I forgot to pass data to the success function

Answer (score 1):

In Ajax Success Function you didn't get the response from controller

```
   success: function(ResponseData){
           if(ResponseData.status == true){
                      clearError();
                      $("#loading").html(loadingtrue());
                   }
                  else{
                      ShowError(ResponseData.error_list); 
                  }      
      }
```

Comment: @Giulia Lage This is the correct answer. You might've been confused by the `data` from ajax parameters with the `data` from the response. You can rename the data param from the success callback to `response` or whatever you want.

Comment: please update your answer with a more detailed version of the `success` method and a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your declaration

```
$data = array();
$data["error_list"] = array();
$data["status"] = false;
```